# Simple bash script sometimes fails

Tags: bash, shell-script, usb

I have a bash script that disables a USB port if there is no internet connection and after five seconds enables it again. But SOMETIMES it fails, the script disables the port but is not enabled again. Note that I only have a one USB port. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true 
do 
    sleep 10                                                
    if ping -c 2 google.com >> /dev/null 2>&1;then                        
        echo $(date  +"%r") >> /root/log.txt
        echo "Conectado a SopelaBari" >> /root/log.txt
    else
        echo $(date  +"%r") >> /root/log.txt
        echo "Sin conexion" >> /root/log.txt
        echo '2-1' |tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
        sleep 5
        echo '2-1' |tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
        sleep 5
    fi 
    sleep 30 
done
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.05 and the script is run as root with crontab.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your script. Try adding `2> /tmp/script.logfile` to the end of your crontab line and see if any error output is generated when it doesn't work. You could also try increasing the `sleep 5` 10 or 20 or so, to be sure it isn't a problem with how long it takes for the port to be disabled/enabled.

Comment: @terdon, thanks for your answer. Do I have to create 2> /tmp/script.logfile directory or is automatically created? I don't think time is a problem, normally it takes less than 1 sec to enable/disable the port.

Comment: The `/tmp` directory is created by default, just add `2> /tmp/script.logfile` and that will create a file called `script.logfile` in `/tmp`. And yes, I agree that it should take less than a second but since you say it usually works, but *sometimes* does not, then we're looking for something strange. So maybe it sometimes takes longer.

Comment: Thanks @terdon. I added the script.logfile and increased the time. I will need some time to reproduce the error. I will tell you something as soon as I can.

Comment: Great! When you have more details, please [edit] your question and add them  there (don't write "edit" or anything, just write your question as if you had included this information from the beginning). That way, the next person to read your question will have all the information.

Comment: Sorry @terdon, I have not get any error until now. Although I don't understand why, maybe it was a time problem. However is it possible to modify my crontab command to  make this bash script to re-start if it crashes ? Now I use this command '@reboot /root/wifi.sh 2> /root/script.logfile'. However I will be still looking if I can get any error from script.logfile file. Thanks.

Comment: You would probably have to modify the script itself to keep trying until it works. But I can't really help since we don't know where or even if it crashes.

Comment: @terdon, finally I found the error. "tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind: No such device". Maybe the usb has change the port?Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how the usb subsystem works. I suggest you just delete this (or, if you prefer, post an answer explaining that the file sometimes disappears and accept it) and ask a new question about how you can reliably enable and disable a usb device. Show your script, explain that you have found that it sometimes fails because `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind` doesn't exist, and ask for a better way.